# Python: Pie chart percentages greater than number

Tags: python, charts

I need to plot a pie chart of frequencies from a column of a dataframe, but a lot of lower frequencies appear and visualization is poor.

the code I wrote is :

```
df[column].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind="pie")
```

I know that `df[column].value_counts(normalize=True)` will give me percentages of every unique value, but I want to apply the filter `percentage>0.05`

What I tried?:

```
new_df = df[column].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

but this gives me `column` as index, so I reset the index

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

and then tried

```
new_df.plot(kind = "pie")
```

but nothing appears.

I want some 1 line code that can make something like:

```
df[column].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind="pie" if value_counts > 0.05)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['column'].value_counts()[df['column'].value_counts(normalize=True)>0.05].plot(kind='pie')
```